# Laravel 5 App Namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, eloquent, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5.

I set the original app up and running in Homestead. When I wrote a simple UserTableSeeder and tried to seed the MYSQL database using artisan, a error popped out: "Class User not found".

Well, I did not change anything in the "app/User.php" file and after I added the namespace *App* to the seeder code,

that is, from

```
User::create(array(..));
```

to

```
App\User::create(array(..));
```

the seeding worked just fine.

Same thing happened when I was trying to use

```
User::all();
```

or other Eloquent query operations in "routes.php". Only when I added the namespace *App\* would it work out.

I have tried *composer dump-autoload* and I made sure the app name and the "composer.json" file was exactly the same as the original code in Laravel 5.

Do we have to add the namespace *App/* whenever we want to use the models in Laravel 5?

I think I might have got something wrong because in Laravel 4 we do not have to add the namespace *App* in these cases.

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 5, the `app` directory is namespaced under `App` by default. If you look in your `composer.json` you will see that the `app` directory is set up for psr-4 autoloading:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
},
```

When you want to use a class from there or inside a subdirectory, you need to include the namespace. You can also `use` it if you want to just reference the class name as is. For example:

**app/Namespace/SomeClass.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Namespace;

use App\User;

class SomeClass {

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually do not understand what `"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}` stands for. And the "classmap" under "autoload" is different from that in Laravel 4.2. This got me really confused as I did not grasp how composer works.

Comment: No problem. PSR-4 is just a standard for autoloading. You can read more about it here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. There's nothing too complicated you need to know, just that files under your app directory should be namespaced in a way that follows the folder structure. You won't need to dump your autoload every time you add a new class as the entire directory is auto-loaded